# SnipCart API Authorization returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-mvc-5, snipcart

I want to use the V3 SnipCart API to get data about specific orders on my thank you page. I am using C# to do this. I keep getting this error when trying to use the API

> System.Net.WebException:'The remote server returned an error: (401)
> Unauthorized.'

I have tried to follow their documentation by using only the API key with no password as shown [here](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/api-reference/authentication). Below is my code that I wrote that is giving me the error. I wrote this inside my controller. I get the error as soon as the breakpoint hits this line responseObjGet = (HttpWebResponse)requestObjGet.GetResponse();

```
//Testing API get data begin
        string strurltest = String.Format("https://app.snipcart.com/api/orders/c5541254-r8541-8501-0024-juy85vv002154");
       
        WebRequest requestObjGet = WebRequest.Create(strurltest);
        requestObjGet.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("HihiukoJOUBVCTYIiijiGiiYTd6tOiUyTYo", "");
        

        requestObjGet.Method = "GET";
        
        HttpWebResponse responseObjGet = null;
        responseObjGet = (HttpWebResponse)requestObjGet.GetResponse(); //401 is triggered here

        string strresulttest = null;
        using (Stream stream = responseObjGet.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            strresulttest = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();

        }
```

Concerns that I have as well are the following:
1.The API key that I entered here is my public api key since I am still in the development and testing phase. I am not sure if this api call will work with the test api key or if I have to use the real secret production key. Any thoughts?

2.I am debugging this off my local machine (localhost:) for now before I deploy these API calls to production to test these changes in prod still with the test api key, could that be a reason for the 401? Since the URL that is trying to get the info is my localhost: url and not my actual domain that I added to SnipCart Dashboard. I was thinking maybe I have to try and hit this from prod environment instead? Any thought?

These are the 2 possibilities that come to mind for me. I am not too savvy on APi's yet so I don't know if my call is missing something.

Summary: All I am trying to do is be able to use the API so that I can load the data I want for an order when users reach my custom thank you page with their token.

Comment: `responseObjGet.Headers.Add("Authorization", Basic <<YOUR_SECRET_API_KEY>>);`

Answer (score 0):

Our 401 "Unauthorized" status code is returned when the authentication failed to our API with your Authorization header's value.

[Here's the documentation about the auth to our APIs](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/api-reference/authentication). Make sure to return us a base64 value of your secret API key and the trailing single colon character at the end to respect the [Basic Authentication Scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7617).

And if you are trying to get data for an order that was placed in live mode then you would need to use the live secret API key.